# shell entering each folder and zip content

Tags: shell

So I have some folder

```
|-Folder1
||-SubFolder1
||-SubFolder2
|-Folder2
||-SubFolder3
||-SubFolder4
```

Each subfolder contains several jpg I want to zip to the root folder...
I'm a little bit stuck on "How to enter each folder"

Here is my code:

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.jpg' | while IFS= read i 
do
   foldName=${PWD##*/}
    zip ../../foldName *
done
```

The better would be to store FolderName+SubFolderName and give it to the zip command as name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dirname` to get the directory name of a file/directory it is located in. 
You can also simplify the `find` command to search only for directories  by using `-type d`. Then you should use `basename` to get only the name of the subdirs:

```
find ./*/* -type d | while read line; do
  zip  --junk-paths "$(basename $line)" $line/*.jpg
done
```

**Explanation**

- `find ./*/* -type d`
  will print out all directories located in `./*/*`  which will result in all subdirs of directories located in the current dir
- `while read line` reads each line from the stream and stores it in the variable "line". Thus $line will be the relative path to the subdir, e.g. "Folder1/Subdir2"
- `"$(basename $line)"` returns the only the name of the subdir, e.g. "Subdir2"
- Update: add --junk-paths to the zip command if you do not want the directy paths to be stored in the zip filde

Comment: Just dont get what "line" is in the first place...than the chain $name $line doesn't give Folder1+SubFolder1 name

Comment: The funny thing is that that was a solution that should have make me save time :D you know instead of doing it manually... :D

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer. It should be `basename` not `dirname`, since we are searching for dirs with `find` now. I have also removed the variable "name". There is actually no need to create it. "line" is just a variable which holds the current line from the stream (you can rename it i or so). Also read [this xkcd](http://xkcd.com/1205/) ;)

Comment: Ok I just modified it in zip "$(basename "$line")" $line/*.jpg because subfoders has spaces in name but I got a 

zip warning: name not matched: ./vol.1/Hinata
zip warning: name not matched: 01/*.jpg

(the name of the subfolder is Hinata 01, Hinata 02 etc...). And thanks for the awesome link :P

Comment: Definitly it was not worth to do a bash but still I think this was a good idea because I'm learnig and this is worthless ;)

Answer (score 1):

### Zipping JPEGs (for Compression) is Usually Wasted Effort

First of all, attempting to compress already-compressed formats like JPEG files is usually a waste of time, and can sometimes result in archives that are larger than the original files. However, it is sometimes useful to do so for the convenience of having a bunch of files in a single package.

Just something to keep in mind. YMMV.

### Use Find's `-execdir` Flag

What you need is the *find* utility's `-execdir` flag. The GNU find man page says:

> ```
>    -execdir command {} +
>           Like -exec, but the specified command is run from the  subdirec‐
>           tory  containing  the  matched  file,  which is not normally the
>           directory in which you started find.
> ```

For example, given the following test corpus:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir -p foo/bar/baz
touch foo/bar/1.jpg
touch foo/bar/baz/2.jpg
```

you can zip the entire set of files with find while excluding the path information with a single invocation. For example:

```
find /tmp/foo -name \*jpg -execdir zip /tmp/my.zip {} +
```

### Use Zip's `--junk-paths` Flag

The zip utility on many systems supports a `--junk-paths` flag. The man page for *zip* says:

> ```
>   --junk-paths
>           Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do  not
>           store  directory names.
> ```

So, if your find utility doesn't support `-execdir`, but you *do* have a zip that supports junking paths, you could do this instead:

```
find /tmp/foo -name \*jpg -print0 | xargs -0 zip --junk-paths /tmp/my.zip
```

Comment: The reason why I want to zip is that the resulting .zip will be renamed .cbr (so it will me read by a Comic Reader program). I will check out your tips, thanks

Comment: So my system actually supports -execdir. According to what you say my bash can stand on a only line: --> find ./*/* -type d -name \*jpg -execdir zip "$line".zip {} +  <-- but it actually doesn't work and no error or warning is given

Comment: @Michele You're adding flags and options of your own that are causing you trouble. Your path specification is wrong, and you're only returning directories with the `-type d` flag. The command itself works as I posted it; you need to fix your invocation and do some troubleshooting if you're going to make significant changes.

Comment: Why is the path wrog? I am looking for any SubFolder in any Folder so find ./*/* should do it

Answer (score 0):

So a little check, I finally got something working:

```
find ./*/* -type d | while read line; do
  #printf '%s\n' "$line"
  zip ./"$line" "$line"/*.jpg
done
```

But this create un archive containing:

```
Subfolder.zip
Folder
|-Subfolder
||-File1.jpg
||-File2.jpg
||-File3.jpg
```

Instead I fold like it to be:

```
Subfolder.zip
|-File1.jpg
|-File2.jpg
|-File3.jpg
```

So I tried using basename and dirname in differnet combination...Always got some error...
And just to learn how to: what if I would like the new archive to be created in the same root directory as "Folder"?

Comment: You have to add --junk-paths to the zip command. I tested it and it gives me the result you want even with spaces in the names of the subfolders

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally got it!

```
find ./* -name \*.zip -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf

find ./*/* -type d | while read line; do
  #printf '%s\n' "$line"
  zip --junk-paths ./"$line" "$line"/*.jpg
done

find . -name \*.zip -type f -mindepth 2 -exec mv -- '{}' . \;
```

In first row I simply remove all .zip files,

Then I zip all and in the final row I move all zip to the root directory!

Thanks everbody for your help!